# How to set dynamic block-container size that occupies the rest of the page

Tags: xsl-fo

I have been struggling with xls-fo because of a severe lack of examples.

I want to generate a dynamic invoice which has the grand total at the bottom of the page.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have been trying with height="100%" with block-container and table, then try to set position relative to the bottom. The interpreter doesn't recognise percentage height and I have no luck at all.

Relative positioning also doesn't work. I don't know the right syntax. I can see some work has been done with fo:conditional-page-master-reference. I don't even know how to apply for that page-sequence-master.

Can you give me the simplest working xsl-fo structure for this layout?

Comment: additional question: I tried to generate some sample code with chatGPT, Bing and Bard. None of them can give me any working code. They just lie to me. I'm badly hurt :/ Where can I find resources of working code of different tags?

Comment: Antenna House Formatter samples are at https://www.antennahouse.com/xsl-fo-samples. There's also "How to Develop Stylesheets for XML to XSL-FO Transformation" available at https://www.antennahouse.com/xml-to-xsl-fo-stylesheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to generate an `fo:footnote` at the end of the last `fo:block`.  There are multiple `fo:footnote` examples at https://www.antennahouse.com/xsl-fo-samples.

If you are using Antenna House Formatter, you could make an `fo:float` that floats to the bottom of the page. See https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-float.html

The `fo:conditional-page-master-reference` way would also work. There's also a sample for that at https://www.antennahouse.com/xsl-fo-samples.

To get the grand total into the footer of the only or last page would also require that you use `fo:static-content`, `fo:marker`, and `fo:retrieve-marker`. There's also `fo:marker` samples, plus markers are covered in "How to Develop Stylesheets for XML to XSL-FO Transformation" available at https://www.antennahouse.com/xml-to-xsl-fo-stylesheets.

Comment: Hi Tony, thank you for the solution. Yes it works most of the times. But when the remaining space is less than the footnote as the first 2-pages illustration shows, Acrobat can't be bother to display the footnote in the next page. Any solutions for this?

Comment: Unforfunately, I'm not allowed to use any proprietory solutions, like Antennahouse :-/

Comment: Only the bottom float idea uses an Antenna House extension. The rest are vanilla XSL 1.1.

Comment: I have explored a bit of Antenna House's examples. I realised the problem may be caused by the renderer of the Xsl-FO to PDF engine. Currently we are using Fonet 1.0.0 released in 2011. I think height="100%" was not supported. Do you think putting the Grand Total section into a separate page is possible using this version?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about how to use marker and static-content. I have checked out the marker example in AXF. It only shows how to display index numbers to the right. It doesn;t solve my problem that anything falls outside of normal flow and does not have enough space will not get displayed. Static-content will display the content in every page which is not what I wanted. The grand total is only shown on the last page.

Comment: You said everything except float is vanilla XSL 1.1. Say flow-name="xsl-footnote-separator mentioned in the footnote example. It can't be compiled by Fonet. I don't know whether it's because Fonet is too old or xsl-footnote-separator is only defined by AXF

Comment: I suspect that Fonet is both old and incomplete. `xsl-footnote-separator` was in XSL 1.0 from 2001. It appears 19 times in the XSL 1.1 spec, e.g., in https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#flow-name.

Comment: I was going to add that it could be done with an absolutely positioned `fo:block-container` as well, but I suspect that Fonet also won't support that.

Comment: I reckon it's impossible to achieve my goal using Fonet. It doesn't have the ability to calculate the space to be used before writing out the layout