# What's the latest version of xsl-fo renderer can I get for .net framework 4.5.1

Tags: xsl-fo

I am working for a .Net framework 4.5.1 project. The project is consist of a PDF generator which deploys Fonet Xsl-FO to PDF Rendering Engine version 1.0.0. I found it was released in 2011, more than 10 years ago. A lot of FO tags and attributes are not supported, such as region-start&end, bottom etc.

What is the latest FO engine is available for .NET Framework? I am so frustrated with [setting a grand total section at the bottom of the last page of a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77544580/how-to-set-dynamic-block-container-size-that-occupies-the-rest-of-the-page/77545076?noredirect=1#comment136711632_77545076). I think it's impossible to do with Fonet 1.0.0. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antenna House Formatter has a .Net interface: https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-dotnet.html

It has been tested with Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2.